# Applying Neumann series

Tags: real-analysis, banach-spaces

> Let $E$ be a Banach space. Let $A \in L(E)$, the space of linear operators from $E$. Show that the linear operator $\varphi: L(E) \to L(E)$ with $\varphi (T) = T + AT$ is an isomorphism if $\|A\| < 1$.

So the idea here is to use the Neumann series but I can't really figure out how to apply it here. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to note that $\varphi (T)=(I+A)T $. As $\|A\|<1$, the element $I+A $ ($=I-(-A) $) is invertible, with inverse
$$
B=\sum_{k=0}^\infty  (-1)^kA^k.
$$
Then  $\psi (T)=BT $ is the inverse of $\varphi $.